# how can i display border height and width in pixel in chrome or firefox to test for responsive webdesign

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Since today in the morning I am searching for an add on for chrome or firefox which shows me the border lines(height, width) of page, so that i can test my page by resizing and watching its heights and widths in border lines.

i tried, `window resizer`, `Web Developer` and a bunch of others.. but they dont show me dynamically the borders of page in pixels during resize.

i hope, i explained it clearly

example: [image]

Comment: You mean like this: http://www.dimensionsapp.com/

Comment: @Jonathan, yes, exactly, but is there any integrated version so that i can see it in every tab i open right inside my normal browser?

Comment: You can use ctrl+shift+m on Firefox

Comment: IE devtools have a resize option under the 'Extra' tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome, there is a "gear" icon to the bottom right of the development tools (right-click on any element, then "Inspect Element") that opens up the general settings. Just check "Show Rulers" in the "Elements" section, then hover on elements in the HTML code in the Elements pane.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i need those pixels be shown automatically. here i have to hover the elements right?

Comment: Right, I think you would need to hover over the elements (in the HTML code), unless there is a feature/setting I have missed. The rulers are also displayed when you resize the window, which can be useful for testing responsive designs.

Answer (score 4):

In Firefox you can also select "Responsive design view" from the web developer menu. This allows you to resize a page and make it responsive in a much more interactive way.